# What is the distribution of $c^x$? ($c$ is a constant, $x$ is a random variable)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

What is the distribution of $c^x$, where $c$ is a constant and $x$ is a random variable?

For example, $x$ follows a Poisson distribution, what is the distribution of $2^x$?

Comment: Well, it can take on the values $2^0, 2^1, 2^2,\ldots$ and it takes on the value $2^n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with probability $P(X=n)$.

Comment: I do not know of a *special name* for the distribution of $2^X$ when $X$ is Poisson. But the probability mass function can be written down using the pmf of the Poisson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $c>0$, the function $g(x)=c^x$ is a bijection and you have for $Y=c^X$:

$\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq \log_{c}y)  $
Now you can differentiate:

> $$f_Y(y)=\frac{d}{dy}\mathbb{P}(X\leq \log_{c}y)=\frac{1}{y\ln c}f_X(\log_{c}y)$$

For the discrete case, you get $\mathbb{P}(Y=y)=\mathbb{P}(X=\log_{c}y)$. So for X a Poisson RV, you get:

> $$
> \mathbb{P}(Y=2^n)=\frac{\lambda^ne^{-\lambda}}{n!}.
> $$
>   $\mathbb{P}(Y=k)=0$ for $\log_2 k\notin\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Comment: This answer is oriented towards continuos variables, the OP is insterested in $X$ discrete (Poisson)

Comment: @leonbloy, The question was about general random variable. Poisson was an example, however for the discrete case it is rather easy. anyway I added it to the answer.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

$\xi = c^{x}\quad$. ${\rm P}\,$: $x$ distribution. $\quad{\cal P}\,$: $\xi$ distribution. $\quad{\large c > 0}$.

\begin{align}
{\cal P}\left(\xi\right)
&=
{{\rm d} \over {\rm d}\xi}
\int_{-\infty}^{\xi}{\cal P}\left(\xi'\right)\,{\rm d}\xi'
=
{{\rm d} \over {\rm d}\xi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\rm P}\left(x\right)\,\Theta\left(\xi - c^{x} \right)\,{\rm d}x
=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\rm P}\left(x\right)\,\delta\left(\xi - c^{x} \right)\,{\rm d}x
\\[3mm]&=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\rm P}\left(x\right)\,
{\delta\left(x - \ln\left(\xi\right)/\ln\left(c\right) \right)
 \over
 \left\vert c^{x}\ln\left(c\right)\right\vert}\,{\rm d}x
=
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline
\\
{\large\quad%
{{\rm P}\left(\ln\left(\xi\right)/\ln\left(c\right)\right)
 \over
 \xi\,\left\vert\ln\left(c\right)\right\vert}\quad}
\\ \\
\hline
\end{array}
\end{align}